# Compute complex equation $\rho^2 e^{2i\theta}+ 3\rho e^{-i\theta}=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried compute equation:
$$ z^{2} + 3\overline z = 0 $$ 
using method with polar reprezentation.
$$ z = re^{i\theta} $$

$$\rho^2 e^{2i\theta}+ 3\rho e^{-i\theta}=0$$
$\color{red}{\text{assume that } \rho > 0}$
$$\color{red}\rho=-3e^{-3i\theta}$$
As $\rho$ is positive and real, and exponential of an imaginary argument is on a unit circle, you know that the only solution is $\color{red}{\rho=3}$ and $e^{-3i\theta}=-1=e^{i\pi}$ meaning
$$-3i\theta = i\pi k$$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$
and $$\theta = -\pi/3k$$ so
$$\theta\in\lbrace \pi/3, 2\pi/3 \rbrace$$

and get the solution $z=0$ (from $\rho=0$),

Please check my solution. Thanks

Comment: @Winther, yes, this is mistake

Comment: Next remember that $e^z = e^w$ says that $z = w + 2\pi i k$, not $z = w*k$. For example in the result you have found $k=0$ gives $\theta = 0$ which is not a solution.

Comment: So we have $\theta = -\frac{1}{3}\pi(1 + 2k)$ and $\theta\in\lbrace -\pi/3, -\pi \rbrace$ @Winther

Comment: Yes, but $k$ can be any integer so why did you stop at $k=0,1$ ? You are missing one solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $$\rho^2 e^{2i\theta}+ 3\rho e^{-i\theta}=0$$

You should have concluded

$$\rho = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad \rho = -3e^{-3i\theta}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy$ then we get
$$x^2-y^2+3x+i(2xy-3y)=0$$ so
$$x^2-y^2+3x=0$$ and $$2xy-3y=0$$

From the second equation  we get
$$y=0$$

or $$2x-1=0$$